# How to scroll to item when appended?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list-group in my container that will have dynamically added `X items` and I would be able to scroll to the last item when it's added.

I was trying to use `.animate({ scrollTop: list.prop("scrollHeight") },500);` as it worked as solution in other questions but it's not working in my case.

Here is my code where I simulate with a static array the appending of items with a delay:

```js
var prodotti = [{
    desc: "Prosciutto",
    qta: 2,
    prezzo: 2
  },
  {
    desc: "Carne",
    qta: 1,
    prezzo: 15
  },
  {
    desc: "Pomodori",
    qta: 6,
    prezzo: 3
  },
  {
    desc: "Pandoro",
    qta: 5,
    prezzo: 22
  },
  {
    desc: "Yougurt",
    qta: 3,
    prezzo: 5
  },
  {
    desc: "Pomodori",
    qta: 6,
    prezzo: 3
  },
  {
    desc: "Pandoro",
    qta: 5,
    prezzo: 22
  },
  {
    desc: "Yougurt",
    qta: 3,
    prezzo: 5
  },
  {
    desc: "Pomodori",
    qta: 6,
    prezzo: 3
  },
  {
    desc: "Pandoro",
    qta: 5,
    prezzo: 22
  },
  {
    desc: "Yougurt",
    qta: 3,
    prezzo: 5
  }
];
var height = $(".scontrino").height();
$(".list-group").css("max-height", height - 250); // setting the height to list-group
var list = $(".list-group");
$.each(prodotti, function(key, prodotto) {
  $(".btn-finish").removeAttr("disabled");
  list.delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).append(
      $("<li>", {
        class: "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between",
      }).append(
        $("<span>", {
          class: "desc"
        }).text(prodotto.desc),
        $("<span>", {
          class: "qta"
        }).text(prodotto.qta),
        $("<span>", {
          class: "prezzo"
        }).text(prodotto.prezzo)
      )
    );
    next();
  });

  list.animate({
      scrollTop: list.prop("scrollHeight")
    },
    500
  );
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'PTSans', Fallback, sans-serif;
  background: #00383e;
  height: 100%;
}

.scontrino {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f7f5;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.scontrino:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.scontrino:after {
  bottom: -14px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%);
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: #00383e;
}

.list-group {
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.list-group-item {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-top-width: 1px !important;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="scontrino">
      <h4>Il tuo carrello</h4>
      <hr />
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
      <hr />
      <div class="alert alert-dark totale" role="alert">
        Totale
        <span class="price float-right">€0.00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Fidelity
        <span class="float-right">001230013212</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7 p-0 bg-light">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would expect the animate to go somewhere inside the queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the animate to go somewhere inside the queue

```js
var prodotti = [{ desc: "Prosciutto", qta: 2, prezzo: 2 }, { desc: "Carne", qta: 1, prezzo: 15 }, { desc: "Pomodori", qta: 6, prezzo: 3 }, { desc: "Pandoro", qta: 5, prezzo: 22 }, { desc: "Yougurt", qta: 3, prezzo: 5 }, { desc: "Pomodori", qta: 6, prezzo: 3 }, { desc: "Pandoro", qta: 5, prezzo: 22 }, { desc: "Yougurt", qta: 3, prezzo: 5 }, { desc: "Pomodori", qta: 6, prezzo: 3 }, { desc: "Pandoro", qta: 5, prezzo: 22 }, { desc: "Yougurt", qta: 3, prezzo: 5 } ];

var height = $(".scontrino").height();
$(".list-group").css("max-height", height - 250); // setting the height to list-group
var list = $(".list-group");
$.each(prodotti, function(key, prodotto) {
  $(".btn-finish").removeAttr("disabled");
  list.delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).append(
      $("<li>", {
        class: "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between",
      }).append(
        $("<span>", {
          class: "desc"
        }).text(prodotto.desc),
        $("<span>", {
          class: "qta"
        }).text(prodotto.qta),
        $("<span>", {
          class: "prezzo"
        }).text(prodotto.prezzo)
      )
    )  .animate({ scrollTop: list.prop("scrollHeight") }, 500 );;
    next();
  })



});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'PTSans', Fallback, sans-serif;
  background: #00383e;
  height: 100%;
}

.scontrino {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f7f5;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.scontrino:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.scontrino:after {
  bottom: -14px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%);
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: #00383e;
}

.list-group {
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.list-group-item {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-top-width: 1px !important;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="scontrino">
      <h4>Il tuo carrello</h4>
      <hr />
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
      <hr />
      <div class="alert alert-dark totale" role="alert">
        Totale
        <span class="price float-right">€0.00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Fidelity
        <span class="float-right">001230013212</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7 p-0 bg-light">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, i've actually yet tryed to set it directly and even by just doing the animate before next(); but it's not working anyway and it's like the scroll get broken when animate is before next() as if i scroll manually to top it's scrolling slowly and buggy [GIF of it's behavior when animate is before next()](https://i.gyazo.com/9775c5a17c82079b2357755b39c24167.gif)

Comment: Oh just cheked it better and it's scrolling down only after all items has been added to the list and still bug the scroll

Comment: That seems to be a bug only when `.delay().queue` is used as if i use it in onClick environment it's working well